# How to set request headers in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

Hi I am working on RoR project with ruby-2.5.0 and Rails 5. I am using rspec to test my code. i have a controller where i am using before_action to validate user's token as follows:-

```
abc_controller.rb
class ParserController < ApplicationController
  before_action :validate_token

  def create
    store_name,reciept = StoreParserInteractor.find_store(parser_params,@user_id)
    if reciept.present?
      render json: JSONAPI::Serializer.serialize(reciept),
             status: :ok
    elsif store_name.present?
      render json: {'error': 'date / time on receipt not found'},
             status: 400
    else
      render json: {'error': 'store name not found'},
             status: 400
    end
  rescue StandardError
    render json: {}, status: 500
  end

  private

  def parser_params
    params.require(:data)
          .permit!
          .transform_keys(&:underscore)
  end
end
```

My application controller is as follow:-

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
  attr_accessor :user_id

  def validate_token
    auth_interactor = AuthenticationInteractor.new(request.headers['login-token'])
    @user_id = auth_interactor.user_from_token&.id
    render status: 401 unless @user_id
  end
end
```

Inside rspec how can i send auth-token in the header? my rspec is as follow:-

```
describe ParserController do
  describe 'POST create' do
    subject { post :create, params: params }
    context 'when store is found' do
      let(:params) do
         {
    "Lines": [{
            "Words": [{
                "WordText": "WELCOME",
                "Left": 655,
                "Top": 442,
                "Height": 23,
                "Width": 91
            }],
            "MaxHeight": 23,
            "MinTop": 442
        },
        {
            "Words": [{
                    "WordText": "FOR",
                    "Left": 620,
                    "Top": 1785,
                    "Height": 22,
                    "Width": 37
                },
                {
                    "WordText": "CUSTOM",
                    "Left": 738,
                    "Top": 1785,
                    "Height": 22,
                    "Width": 79
                }
            ],
            "MaxHeight": 22,
            "MinTop": 1785
        },

        {
            "Words": [{
                "WordText": "rpos",
                "Left": 477,
                "Top": 1915,
                "Height": 22,
                "Width": 48
            }],
            "MaxHeight": 22,
            "MinTop": 1915
        },
        {
            "Words": [{
                    "WordText": "402!",
                    "Left": 479,
                    "Top": 2209,
                    "Height": 22,
                    "Width": 46
                },
                {
                    "WordText": ".28",
                    "Left": 597,
                    "Top": 2208,
                    "Height": 23,
                    "Width": 37
                }
            ],
            "MaxHeight": 23,
            "MinTop": 2208
        }
    ],
    "HasOverlay": true,
    "Message": "Total lines: 42"
}
      end
  before do
    allow(controller).to receive(:validate_token).and_return(true)
  end

  it { is_expected.to have_http_status(400) }
    end
  end
end
```

I have to pass auth-token inside headers. Please help me how to create user and pass that token inside headers. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass `:headers` as option in the `post` method:

```
it "date / time on receipt not found" do
  my_params = {}
  my_user_token = user.generate_api_token

  post :create, params, headers: { "login-token" => my_user_token }
  # post parsers_path, my_params, headers: { "login-token" => my_user_token }

  expect(response.status).to eq 400
end
```

Comment: Thanks! It was helpfully for me
I updated Rails 4.2.11.1 to 5.0.7
And `cookies[:my_cookie] = 'chocolate_ muffin'` stoped saving